# Error while installing MySQL even after changing the environment file

Tags: apt, java, dpkg, mysql

I am trying to install MySql in my Ubuntu 16.04 machine.

```
$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

I am getting the following error messages.

```
/usr/sbin/update-info-dir: 3: export:
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64: bad variable name 
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:  install-info 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Importantly, in my environment file, I have changed the `JAVA_HOME` variable from its symbolic link to the actual location where Java is located.

Still it throws the same error.

**Previous environment file :**

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/bin/java/bin"
export $JAVA_HOME
```

**Edited environment file :**

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
export $JAVA_HOME
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the actual content of your `/etc/environment` file

Comment: I have added the necessary edits. Pls help.

Comment: @GaneshRamachandran - Why did you change `/etc/environment`?

Comment: Remove the `export $JAVA_HOME` line - `/etc/environment` is not a shell script, it's just a list of name-value pairs

Comment: @steeldriver I removed the export statement and it worked like a boss. Please post your comment as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/etc/environment` file is not a shell script, so you can't place `export` statements in it. It should consist of just name=value pairs. So just remove the line `export $JAVA_HOME` from your file:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
```